# using Angular's ngResource to pass multiple ids as query parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

Is there any way to pass an array for a parameter such that the request URL will result in something like:

GET http://www.myserver.com/products?id=1&id=2&id=3

I tried passing an array as one of the query parameters and this was an epic fail:

```
productService
    .getProducts({
        productId: $scope.selectedProductIds
    })
    .$promise.then(function(result) {
        $scope.productData = result;
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can try http://www.myserver.com/products?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3. Actual syntax depends on what is on server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see console [network tab] here http://jsbin.com/kapuje/1/edit

you can do that in that way :

```
var request = {id:[1,2,3,4]};
postageRate.query(request);
```

Comment: yeah I had tried that... turns out I was working with an empty array ***head-desk***